ASP.NET MVC : in-memory cache options to clear
I am looking into how to use an in-memory cache for data in controller for my API. This endpoint takes in a parameters of type and an id, so I created the key using the id. I would like to know how I can clear the cache for anything that is stored for this key?
Something like Template_ would clear the cache for anything this method created.
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Read(string type, string id)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    GuardKey(Request);
    var template = new Template();
    
    var _cache = new Cache();
    string templateKey = $"Template_{id}";
    template = CacheExtensions.GetOrStore(_cache, templateKey,
                          TemplatesDataService.GetTemplatesByTemplateId(id)
                          .Where(t => t.Status == (short)TemplateMode.Published && t.IsCurrentVersion)
                          .OrderByDescending(t => t.Added)
                          .FirstOrDefault());

    return template;
}

public static class CacheExtensions
{
    private static readonly object sync = new object();
    public const int DefaultCacheExpiration = 60;

    public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, Func<T> generator)
    {
        return cache.GetOrStore(key, (cache[key] == null && generator != null) ? generator() : default(T), DefaultCacheExpiration);
    }

    public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, Func<T> generator, double expireInMinutes)
    {
        return cache.GetOrStore(key, (cache[key] == null && generator != null) ? generator() : default(T), expireInMinutes);
    }

    public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, T 

obj)
{
return cache.GetOrStore(key, obj, DefaultCacheExpiration);
}
    public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, T obj, double expireInMinutes)
    {
        var result = cache[key];

        if (result == null)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                result = cache[key];

                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = obj != null ? obj : default(T);
                    cache.Insert(key, result, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireInMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                }
            }
        }

        return (T)result;
    }

    public static DateTime GetLatestTemplate(this Cache cache, string key)
    {
        var result = cache[key];
        return (DateTime)result;
    }

    public static Boolean IsStored(this Cache cache, string key)
    {
        var result = cache[key];

        if (result == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static Boolean Remove(this Cache cache, string key)
    {
        cache.Remove(key);
        return true;
    }
}

